# If 10/100 ports means the ports can be connected as ethernet and fast ethernet, why show interface status command only show fast ethernet?

Tags: switch

How come the answer for question no. 5 is C? If 10/100 ports means the ports can be connected as ethernet and fast ethernet, why show interface status command only show fast ethernet?

[image]

Figure-1: Screenshot from chapter 5 DIKTA question no. 5, page 108, CCNA 200-301 Official Cert Guide, Volume 1

Comment: That's standard multiple choice answers trying to confuse you...

Comment: Sorry, all *education, certification and homework questions* are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].

Comment: The port is a Fast Ethernet port, even if it's not running Fast Ethernet right now.

Answer (score 2):

Because Catalyst switches label their ports by their type. The speed at which they link does not change the type of port. "Ethernet" would be a 10M port -- or the PTM interface of a VDSL controller, but catalyst switches won't have those.

(NX-OS tends to call everything "Ethernet", but there have been many versions on many different families.)

By the numbers...

- "a" is invalid because port 0/1 is not "Ethernet"
- "b" is invalid because port 0/11 is notconnected
- "d" is invalid because port 0/15 is not "Ethernet"